# Northwind Database Installation Error: Msg 2812, Level 16, State 62, Line 1 Could not find stored procedure 'U'

Tags: northwind

I am trying to install the sample Northwind Database from the file Northwind.sql. When I run the script on SQL Server Express Management Studio I get an error message that says:

Msg 2812, Level 16, State 62, Line 1
Could not find stored procedure 'U'.

I have searched the net but cannot find an easy to follow means of resolving it. Any ideas, please? I am using Windows 8/SQL Server 2012 Express.

Answer (score 10):

Based on the answer by Microsoft [here](https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/738739/could-not-find-stored-proceduresp-dboption-in-sql-server-2012) it need to use `alter database` instead.

open the script and comment following 2 lines.

```
exec sp_dboption 'Northwind','trunc. log on chkpt.','true'
exec sp_dboption 'Northwind','select into/bulkcopy','true'
```

and then add the following line below that

```
alter database Northwind set recovery simple
```

so that it will look like this:

```
-- exec sp_dboption 'Northwind','trunc. log on chkpt.','true'
-- exec sp_dboption 'Northwind','select into/bulkcopy','true'
alter database Northwind set recovery simple
```

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED!

1. I Created a Database with the name Northwind (CREATE Database Northwind)
2. Opened the northwind.sql in Notepad
3. Copied it unto the SQL Server Management Studio
4. Executed the query (ie 3 above)
5. And that's it...

I hope that other users will find this entry useful. I have searched/spent over 6 hours trying to figure this out.

Answer (score 0):

To second Sylva's solved answer above, you have to execute "CREATE" first then if you want to update, then you'll have to execute "ALTER".

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30798057)